# RethinkDB replace query is not working in python

Tags: python, replace, rethinkdb

I'm trying to replace existing document using replace key word.but it's not working. Can someone tell me if there's something i should do additional to this.

```
  r.db("Siyara2D").table("Vessels").get(1).replace({
            "x": "2222",
            "y": "1111",

  }).run(db_connection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the error:

```
Inserted object must have primary key `id`
```

The solution is to keep the primary key in the document. For example:

```
r.db("Siyara2D").table("Vessels").get(1).replace({
    "id": 1,
    "x": "2222",
    "y": "1111",
}).run(db_connection)
```